# bitwise logical operators in COBOL?

Tags: bit-manipulation, cobol, logical-operators, mainframe

How can one express bitwise logical operations in mainframe COBOL?

I have:

```
       01  WRITE-CONTROL-CHAR.
           03  WCC-NOP           PIC X VALUE X'01'.
           03  WCC-RESET         PIC X VALUE X'02'.
           03  WCC-PRINTER1      PIC X VALUE X'04'.
           03  WCC-PRINTER2      PIC X VALUE X'08'.
           03  WCC-START-PRINTER PIC X VALUE X'10'.
           03  WCC-SOUND-ALARM   PIC X VALUE X'20'.
           03  WCC-KEYBD-RESTORE PIC X VALUE X'40'.
           03  WCC-RESET-MDT     PIC X VALUE X'80'.
```

In Micro Focus COBOL, I could do something like:

```
WCC-NOP B-AND WCC-RESET
```

but it seems there's no such operator on the mainframe (or at least not in Enterprise COBOL for z/OS).

Is there some (hopefully straightforward!) way to simulate/replicate bitwise logical operations in mainframe COBOL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet appears to be 'CEESITST', as it appears to exist in z/OS COBOL. I found an example using that as well as the other bit manipulation programs.

http://esj.com/articles/2000/09/01/callable-service-manipulating-binary-data-at-the-bit-level.aspx

Comment: CEESITST is actually a Language Environment callable service, available to any LE-enabled application: Enterprise COBOL, Enterprise PL/I, C/C++ (though those languages have bitwise operators) and Assembler (same).  It's documented, along with the other LE Callable Services, in the Language Environment section of the z/OS Information Center.

Comment: The latest COBOL standard (the year escapes me at the moment) now has bit-manipulation capabilities, as you see in Micro Focus COBOL. Unfortunately, IBM still seems stuck in the past with the 1985 standard + extras (mainly OO COBOL), and shows no signs of bringing Enterprise COBOL into the 21st century.

Comment: You are correct, Enterprise COBOL does not conform to the latest standard.  I'm pretty sure no COBOL compiler completely implements that standard.  IBM is currently running an invitation-only beta for their new COBOL compiler (see http://www-01.ibm.com/software/os/systemz/announcements/apps/).  The extras you refer to also include some pretty nice XML generation and parsing.  I wish they included the ability to sort a Working-Storage or Local-Storage table without writing it to a file first.

Comment: @cschneid sorting a table is now available in V5.2.

Comment: The link "www-01.bim.com/software/os/systemz/announcements/apps" produces "page not found" from IBM's site.

Answer (score 3):

If you `AND` together values that don't share bits, you will *always* get zero, so I'm going to assume you meant `OR`. This makes sense since you tend to `OR` independent bits to construct a multi-bit value.

With that in mind, when the bit masks are independent of each other, as in a single term doesn't interact with other terms, there is no difference between:

```
termA OR termB
```

and:

```
termA + termB
```

Your terms are all independent here, being `x'1'`, `x'2'` and so forth (no `x'03'` or `x'ff'`) so adding them should work fine:

```
COMPUTE TARGET = WCC-NOP + WCC-RESET
```

Now that's good for setting bits starting with nothing, but not so useful for clearing them. However, you can use a *similar* trick for clearing:

```
COMPUTE TARGET = 255 - WCC-NOP - WCC-RESET
```

Setting or clearing them from an arbitrary starting point (regardless of their current state) is a little trickier and can't be done easily with addition and subtraction.